# Kestrel HTTPS Endpoint with Wildcard Certificate

Tags: asp.net-core, https, ssl-certificate, wildcard, kestrel-http-server

We are facing an issue when we load a wildcard certificate for a Kestrel ASP.NET Web API host using the following `appsettings.json` file:

```
"Kestrel": {
  "EndPoints": {
    "HttpsInlineCertStore": {
      "Url": "https://test.my.host.com:443",
      "Certificate": {
        "Subject": "*.host.com",
        "Store": "My",
        "Location": "LocalMachine",
        "AllowInvalid": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In Chrome, we receive the `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error, and in Firefox `SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN`.

Naturally the domain in the URL does not align with the wildcard certificate, but we are not sure how to rectify this issue.

[image]

Comment: The wildcard certificate is valid for *.host.com, not for `*.*.host.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the issue was related to the level of the domain and where the wildcard `*` is positioned.

`*.host.com` will only match a single level of sub-domains, and not "sub-sub-domains".

So `testmy.host.com` works, but not `test.my.host.com`. For the latter to work, another wildcard cert `*.my.host.com` would be required.

Comment: We just hit the exact same issue. A colleague did use dot notation for the name of the machine, so we had `*.*.*.domain.com`. He started out with a FQDN single certificate and got it working. Then we switched to wildcard and he said that it didn't work. Turns out the wildcard works, if we moved away from the dot notation in the name of the machine.